# Class template function for input stream reading - C++

Tags: c++, class, templates, methods, dynamic

I'm a little stuck on my current project. I created a method in a class that reads in input from a file, and sends it to an array of Result objects (class). When I do so, it uses the Result classes input stream method to read in the input the way I want. Now I have a custom class template called Vector for dynamic arrays, where Result is my Vector. How would I need to change my input syntax and what kind of method would I need in Vector? The method I used for reading into an array of results objects is this:

```
void Registration::SetSemester(unsigned semester1){
   semester = semester1;
}

void Registration::readFile(istream &input){
    long studentid1;
    unsigned semester1;

    input >> studentid1 >> semester1 >> count;

    SetStudentID(studentid1);
    SetSemester(semester1);

    for(unsigned i = 0; i < count; i++){
        input >> results[i];
    }
}
```

This is my Vector.h:

```
#ifndef VECTOR_H
#define VECTOR_H
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

template <class T>
class Vector
{
    public:
        Vector(int size = 10);
        ~Vector();

        void initialize(unsigned from = 0);
        void expand();
        void add(const T &obj);
        int size() const{return this->nrofel;}

        T& operator[](const int index);
        const T& operator[](const int index) const;

    private:
        T **data;
        unsigned capacity;
        unsigned nrofel;
};

template <class T>
Vector<T>::Vector(int size){
    this->capacity = size;
    this->nrofel = 0;
    this->data = new T*[this->capacity];

    this->initialize();
}

template <class T>
T& Vector<T>::operator[](int index){
    if(index < 0 || index > this->nrofel){
        throw("Out of bounds");
    }
    return *this->data[index];
}

template <class T>
const T& Vector<T>::operator[](int index) const{
    if(index < 0 || index > this->nrofel){
        throw("Out of bounds");
    }
    return *this->data[index];
}

template <class T>
void Vector<T>::initialize(unsigned from){
    for(size_t i = from; i < this->capacity; i++){
        this->data[i] = nullptr;
    }
}

template <class T>
Vector<T>::~Vector(){
    for(size_t i = 0; i < capacity; i++){
        delete this->data[i];
    }
    delete[]this->data;
}

template <class T>
void Vector<T>::expand(){
    this->capacity *= 2;
    T** tempData = new T*[this->capacity];
    for(size_t i = 0; i < this->nrofel; i++){
        tempData[i] = new T(*this->data[i]);
    }

    for(size_t i = 0; i < this->nrofel; i++){
       delete this->data[i];
    }

    delete[] data;
    this->data = tempData;
    this->initialize(this->nrofel);
}

template <class T>
void Vector<T>::add(const T &obj){
    if(this->nrofel >= this->capacity){
        this->expand();
    }
    this->data[this->nrofel++] = new T(obj);
}
```

My add method handles objects and pretty much any value, but how do I make the method available for input from a file into the array?

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this you need to define some type of serialization format for your vector type, and you also need to rely on the contained type to know how to serialize and deserialize itself.

Serialization and deserialization could both be implemented as operators, and they wouldn't even need to be friends of your vector since they can work against the public interface.

Here is some pseudo-code you could flesh out:

```
template <typename T>
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & stream, Vector<T> const & vec) {
    // Possibly write length information using vec.size()
    if (stream << vec.size()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i) {
            // Possibly frame the data; regardless, write out each element using:
            if (!(stream << vec[i])) { break; }
        }
    }

    return stream;
}

template <typename T>
std::istream & operator>>(std::istream & stream, Vector<T> & vec) {
    // Possibly read length information...
    int size;
    if (stream >> size) {
        while (size--) {
            // Possibly read framing.
            T value;
            if (!(stream >> value)) { break; }
            vec.add(value);
        }
    }

    return stream;
}
```

This obviously isn't a complete implementation.  You'll likely want to frame each element somehow so you know where each begins and ends.

`T` needs an implementation of the streaming operators for this to compile.

---

Side note: your `Vector` template violates the [rule of three/five](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)); you define a custom destructor but you do not implement a copy constructor, copy-assignment operator, move constructor, or move-assignment operator.  If you make a value-wise copy of a `Vector`, destruction of the copy source or destination is going to cause undefined behavior when the other object is used.

The simplest fix for this problem, assuming a C++11 compiler, is to delete those members so the compiler doesn't generate the incorrect versions:

```
template <class T>
class Vector
{
public:
    Vector(Vector const &) = delete;
    Vector(Vector &&) = delete;

    Vector & operator=(Vector const &) = delete;
    Vector & operator=(Vector &&) = delete;

    // ...
};
```

In older versions of C++, declare the members private but don't provide an implementation.  This will prevent copying from outside of the class or its friends, and will cause a link-time error if privileged code tries to make a copy:

```
template <class T>
class Vector
{
private:
    // Don't implement any of these!
    Vector(Vector const &);
    Vector(Vector &&);

    Vector & operator=(Vector const &);
    Vector & operator=(Vector &&);

public:
    // ...
};
```

Of course, if possible, you should implement these so that your type can be properly copied/moved.